# Setting the frame of a sublayer inside of layoutSubviews() makes changing it impossible. Any workaround for that?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uitextfield

I'm working on a customizable UITextField (see code below). I have added a border at the bottom (you can set it in the storyboard). However, I had problems setting the frame of the CALayer that this border consists of.

If I set it inside the `didSet` method of `var showBottomBorder` it doesn't appear on the screen. I think this is because the frame (of the UITextField) hasn't been calculated yet (maybe `didSet` gets called before that).

So I moved it to the `layoutSubviews()` method (see code below). This works perfectly.

But now I have another problem. I can't really change that frame anymore. Every time I change it, it gets reset by `layoutSubviews()` which I think is called then.

At the bottom of my code, there is the method `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. In there, I wanted to move up my bottom border (animated). But it doesn't work. The border does not move anywhere. And like I said, I think it's because I set the frame inside the `layoutSubviews()` method.

Is there a better way to set the frame of the bottom border? A way which allows me to change stuff?

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomizableTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties
    private var bottomBorder = CALayer()

    // MARK: - @IBInspectables
    @IBInspectable var roundCorners: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = roundCorners
            self.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    /** -- */
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    /** -- */

    /** -- */
    private var showBottomBorder: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            switch showBottomBorder {
            case true:
                bottomBorder.borderColor = self.bottomBorderColor.cgColor
                bottomBorder.borderWidth = self.bottomBorderWidth

                self.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
                self.layer.masksToBounds = true
                break
            case false:
                bottomBorder.removeFromSuperlayer()
                break
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomBorderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            self.showBottomBorder = false
            self.showBottomBorder = true
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomBorderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            self.showBottomBorder = false
            self.showBottomBorder = true
        }
    }
    /** -- */

    /** -- */
    // Somwhow, the default panel for my font color doesn't change anything, so I created this
    @IBInspectable var fixedFontColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            self.textColor = fixedFontColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var placeholderFontColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            var placeholderTxt = ""
            if let txt = self.placeholder {
                placeholderTxt = txt
            }

            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderTxt, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderFontColor])
        }
    }
    /** -- */

    // MARK: - Overrides and Initializers
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // HERE
        bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - self.bottomBorderWidth, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    }

    // setting the textField delegate to self
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        //self.borderStyle = .none
        self.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - Events
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and **extension** on UITextFiled for setting the border.

And keep a reference to it with **KVC**.

By overriding **LayoutSubview**, every the layout will change, we'l check if the border exists, if so remove it, and re-create a new one with the new frame:

```
import UIKit

let MyTopBorder = "myTopBorder"
let MyBottomBorder = "myBottomBorder"
struct Defaults {
    static let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    static func bottonBorderFrame(view: UIView)->CGRect {
     return CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: view.frame.size.height - Defaults.width,   width:  view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }
    static func topBorderFrame(view: UIView)->CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0) ,   width:  view.frame.size.width, height: Defaults.width)
    }
}

extension UITextField
{
    func setBottomBorder(color:CGColor)
    {
        if let isBottomBorder = self.getBottomBorderIfExists() {
            isBottomBorder.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        self.setBorderWithFrame(Defaults.bottonBorderFrame(self), color: color, andKey: MyBottomBorder)
    }

    func setTopBorder(color:CGColor)
    {
        if let isTopBorder = self.getTopBorderIfExists() {
            isTopBorder.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        self.setBorderWithFrame(Defaults.topBorderFrame(self), color: color, andKey: MyTopBorder)
    }

    func setBorderWithFrame(frame: CGRect, color: CGColor, andKey: String) {
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        let border = CALayer()
        border.borderColor = color
        border.frame = frame
        border.borderWidth = Defaults.width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.setValue(border, forKey: andKey)
    }

    func removeTopBorder() {
        if let isTopBorder = self.getTopBorderIfExists() {
            self.layer.setValue(nil, forKey: MyTopBorder)
            isTopBorder.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }

    func removeBottomBorder() {
        if let isBottomBorder = self.getBottomBorderIfExists() {
            self.layer.setValue(nil, forKey: MyBottomBorder)
            isBottomBorder.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }

    private func getBorderIfExistsByKey(key: String)->CALayer? {
        if let isBorderSet = self.layer.valueForKey(key) {
            if let borderIsCALayer = isBorderSet as? CALayer {
                return borderIsCALayer
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func getTopBorderIfExists()->CALayer? {
        return self.getBorderIfExistsByKey(MyTopBorder)
    }

    private func getBottomBorderIfExists()->CALayer? {
        return self.getBorderIfExistsByKey(MyBottomBorder)
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Update bottom on frame change
        if let isBottomBorder = self.getBottomBorderIfExists() {
            let borderColor = isBottomBorder .borderColor
            self.removeBottomBorder()
            self.setBottomBorder(borderColor!)
        }
        // Update top on frame change
        if let isTopBorder = self.getTopBorderIfExists() {
            let borderColor = isTopBorder.borderColor
            self.removeTopBorder()
            self.setTopBorder(borderColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
  let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100,y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() // Thie color is for visulizing better
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.setBottomBorder(UIColor.blackColor().CGColor) // Now you have a border
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200) // And the border updated to the new frame
        // Now if you would like to change from bottom to top, simply do this:
        textField.removeBottomBorder()
        textField.setTopBorder(UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I tried animating the frame (in my textEditingBegan method), but nothing happens: `UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {() in
            if let isBorder = self.getBorderIfExists() {
                isBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        })`. Also, I'm not sure if `layoutIfNeeded()`is the right method to call.

Comment: Way are you calling "getBorderIfExists"? You should only call "setBottomBorder". It does the logic by itself. Plus I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Your original question had nothing to do with animations. If you set a border and then change the frame my code works, I've tested it.

Comment: What animation are you trying to achieve? Border from bottom to top? I do not see the input it this. Why not just remove the border from bottom and add it to to top. Maybe you can play with the alpha from 0-1 for better ui..

Comment: I just want the ability to move that CGRect around that is created in the setBottomBorder method

Comment: By moving around you mean that you want it to show at the bottom, and then later move it to the top?

Comment: Not necessarily to the top but anywhere. Its about the possibility

Comment: @Quantm I've edited my answer to support top and bottom borders, and switching between them. You can go by the same pattern and add functionality for left and right borders at your need.